# CSS Border Blending/Transparency

Tags: html, css

So I am trying to get the top and left side of this border to blend into the background, i.e. so there is not a visible line along the edge. I am using the inset value on the border-shadow to appear that these edges blend in, although there seems to be a visible edge where the border is.

Please see snippet:

HTML:

```
<article class="para">
    <h2> X-cessive Overview </h2> 
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nam pretium lectus eget risus tempor eleifend. Nulla facilisi. Mauris non ultrices mi, in tristique enim. Nulla facilisi. Nullam dapibus consectetur eros, sed eleifend ligula tincidunt id. Curabitur non velit non elit volutpat accumsan iaculis id elit. Nullam quis tortor maximus, laoreet sapien id, gravida nibh. Nunc tempor justo gravida magna sodales euismod. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Morbi et diam suscipit, varius ante sagittis, bibendum dolor. Nunc pellentesque molestie.
</article>
```

CSS:

```css
.main {
 background-image: url(../images/backgrounds/exile-main1.png);
 background-size: cover;
 background-repeat: no-repeat;
 width: 100%;
 height: 400px;
 color: #000;
 border-bottom: 2px solid #939799;
}
.main h1 {
 position: relative;
 top: 40px;
 left: 30px;
 color: #424040;
 font-size: 2em;
}
.para {
 width: 33%;
 border-right: 2px solid rgb(237,36,62);
 border-bottom: 2px solid rgb(237,36,62);
 border-top: 10px transparent;
 border-left: 10px transparent;
 padding: 15px;
 position: relative;
 left: 140px;
 top: 110px;
 font-size: 1em;
 border-radius: 20px 20px 20px 20px;
 box-shadow: 20px 20px 60px #fff inset;
 background-color: #939799; 
}
.para h2 {
 font-size: 1.2em;
 text-decoration: underline;
}
```

```html
<article class="para">
    <h2> X-cessive Overview </h2> 
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nam pretium lectus eget risus tempor eleifend. Nulla facilisi. Mauris non ultrices mi, in tristique enim. Nulla facilisi. Nullam dapibus consectetur eros, sed eleifend ligula tincidunt id. Curabitur non velit non elit volutpat accumsan iaculis id elit. Nullam quis tortor maximus, laoreet sapien id, gravida nibh. Nunc tempor justo gravida magna sodales euismod. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Morbi et diam suscipit, varius ante sagittis, bibendum dolor. Nunc pellentesque molestie.
</article>
```

Here is a [Screenshot](https://i.imgsafe.org/469a59fcb0.png) so you can better see the issue.

Comment: increasing the shadow offset doesn't fix the issue ?

Comment: Yes adjusting the inset fixed it, I never thought of trying that :), Just need to remove the top left circular mark now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can adjust the `box-shadow` on `.para` to something like: `box-shadow: 45px 15px 70px #fff inset`

And if the text needs to on top of the grey, add more left padding to `.para` like: `padding: 15px 15px 15px 40px;`

```css
.main {
 background-image: url(../images/backgrounds/exile-main1.png);
 background-size: cover;
 background-repeat: no-repeat;
 width: 100%;
 height: 400px;
 color: #000;
 border-bottom: 2px solid #939799;
}
.main h1 {
 position: relative;
 top: 40px;
 left: 30px;
 color: #424040;
 font-size: 2em;
}
.para {
        width: 33%;
        border-right: 2px solid rgb(237,36,62);
        border-bottom: 2px solid rgb(237,36,62);
        border-top: 10px transparent;
        border-left: 10px transparent;
        padding: 15px 15px 15px 46px; /* Adjust this */
        position: relative;
        left: 140px;
        top: 110px;
        font-size: 1em;
        border-radius: 0 20px 20px 20px; /* Adjust this */
        box-shadow: 45px 15px 70px #fff inset; /* Adjust this*/
        background-color: #939799;
}
.para h2 {
 font-size: 1.2em;
 text-decoration: underline;
}
```

```html
<article class="para">
     <h2> X-cessive Overview </h2> 
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nam pretium lectus eget risus tempor eleifend. Nulla facilisi. Mauris non ultrices mi, in tristique enim. Nulla facilisi. Nullam dapibus consectetur eros, sed eleifend ligula tincidunt id. Curabitur non velit non elit volutpat accumsan iaculis id elit. Nullam quis tortor maximus, laoreet sapien id, gravida nibh. Nunc tempor justo gravida magna sodales euismod. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Morbi et diam suscipit, varius ante sagittis, bibendum dolor. Nunc pellentesque molestie.

    </article>
```

Comment: Thanks, How would i remove the top left border edge though?, seems to be a grey circular edge...

Comment: You could set the `border-radius` to 0 for the top-left corner. Answer updated.